# Where's this vine yard, near water and mountains, in Okanagan Valley?

Tags: identify-this, british-columbia

We travelled to Okanagan Valley  in 2000, but not sure if this was photographed there.

[image]

Comment: What’s the name of this book?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a view of [Vaseux Lake](https://flic.kr/p/7vwimS) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaseux_Lake)), from a position north of it, so view goes to the south. I didn't manage to identify the camera position exactly, it may be somewhere near the [Bighorn Ridge Guest House](https://goo.gl/maps/xy7dsmpgQS7BrJHM8). You can find different versions of the photo featured in the book online, for example:

[image]

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! Have you been here before? How did you identify this?